# Removal of a particular element from an unknown number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main video on my website, with a series of thumbnails on the bottom of the video which has a time binds to each of the thumbnails. I displayed these thumbnails using

```
<img id="thumbnail" src="<?php echo "split_videos/mp4_thumbnails-$x.jpg"; ?>"
onclick="skipto(<?php echo $row_data[$n]; ?>)">
```

in my html. Depends on the value of $row_data[$n], when I select a particular thumbnail, the main video will skip to that particular timing and plays.

What I would like to achieve here is to remove a particular thumbnail. When a thumbnail is selected and the "delete" button is clicked, I want to delete the `<img>` tag corresponds to that particular timing of the video.

However this could not be achieve as the number of `<img>` elements created is different across the videos and I could not really keep track of which timing corresponds to which number of `<img>` element.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is the delete button on the thumbnail or is there only one delete button which handles the deleting of each thumbnail?

Comment: Why do you use `onclick` instead of `$('img').click(function(){})`? Try adding ID to each thumbnail according to timing or something.

Comment: `$("img").on("click",function(){(console.log($(this));});` returns the clicked `<img>`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @anurupr yes there is only one delete button, and depends on which thumbnail I select, it will delete that particular thumbnail. That is what I would like to achieve.

Comment: so just like @Michal said, you can add an ID or better just add a single class `active` and in the onclick event handler for the `delete` button you can remove the img that has the `active` class. using class can help if there is a requirement of deleting multiple thumbnails at once

Comment: @anurupr Thank you for your suggestion. It works. However I am having another issue here. So my ID now is made up of time. I have a function which takes in a `value` as argument. But I want to pass this `value` to `getElementById()`. Something like `getElementById ("0.8")`. How can I do that? I can't do `getElementById(value)` right?

Comment: what is your ID like ? can you give a sample ? does it resemble the `value` you are passing to the function?